# Windows phone 8 delayed input validation

Tags: c#, validation, windows-phone-8

I have a few input boxes that I want to validate before I send the data over to the API server. I want to do the validation *as you type*, but it gets annoying if I keep telling you that your username is too short while you've just started typing it. I also don't want to re-validate on every single keypress because the next keypress invalidates it anyway.

What I do on *Android* is that I have a `Handler` with a number of validation codes, each corresponding to a field that needs validation. Every time that field changes, I clear all the messages in the queue with the matching field ID and put a new one in the queue with *750ms* delay. Once the 750ms is up, my handler is invoked to perform the validation for the field associated with the message's ID. This allows me to perform the validation only after the user has stopped typing in that field for at least 750ms. It also means that if the user types 10 characters 
before the 750ms pause, I only validate once.

Is there a recommended way of doing this on Windows Phone 8 (C#)?

I basically need a low overhead way of queueing a task for delayed execution, with the ability to cancel/reschedule the task.

Most of the validation happens on the device and can be performed on the UI thread, but one field needs to be validated against the server so it'll have to run on a BG thread (e.g. *is this username available?*).

Answer (score 1):

If you bind text box ( text ) to property in view model then by default binding doesn't occur until text box loses focus.

So if you are using the binding technique, which is recommended, you can call your validation code when the property in view model is updated.

Comment: The problem with this is that no validation happens until the user leaves the text box. Imagine a signup page where the button is disabled by default. The user fills in the boxes and remains in the last input box. The button will never become enabled unless the user leaves the field. The only option then becomes the `LostFocus` event, which will trigger too many validation events as mentioned above.

Comment: You can change LostFocus to PropertyChanged but that will lead you to the initial state